# Multiclass classification problem with loose (not quite accurate) labeling. How to approach?

Tags: machine-learning

I'm looking for alt. ways to to build multiclass classification problem described below. The problem with using regular classification algorithms like Decision Tree or Logistic Regression is that they consider one value only to be True Positive, while in my data some classification are loosely done, and by that I mean instead of one single right label, 2 or more could be kindof "right", some of them just a bit more accurate than the others, but only one is always chosen. Here is example to demonstrate what I meant:

| Feature | Label |
| --- | --- |
| 1. "My credentials do not work" | "Can't login" |
| 2. "I do not get email with confirmation code" | "Two Factor Verification Issue" |
| 3. "Do not get a receipt" | "Billing issue" |

Feature #2 is classified as "Two Factor Verification Issue" in the training set, but could be classified as "Can't login", which is Ok too. The classification was done by human in the past, and it was up to human how to label the feature, and someone did really classified "2-factor verification" issues as just "can't login". The dataset is huge and re-labeling is not possible. Due to such labeling **ambiguity** training score comes out pretty lame.

I think about ways to better measure quality of a training: What if algorithm offers 2-3 options of classification outcome, and if at least one of them matches defined label, we count it as a successful guess. However a gap in my knowledge of machine learning algorithms do not let me figure out how to do that. Any suggestions? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, it seems that the classes of your labels are not mutually exclusive. There is a overlap among classes and there are genuine cases where more then one label are right. This is usually not a good idea and can happen when you are looking at classes at too high level.
The right way would be to redefine the classes to maybe something more clear and low level such as: "email loss", "credential mismatch" etc. Higher level classes, such as "login issue", can be a combination of such low level classes in application but model should only look at low level classes.

However since you already have the data and can't re-label as you mentioned I would recommend doing 2 things.

1. Define the problem as a multi-label problem instead of a multi-classification problem. In multi label you are trying to give a separate score to each class of label and multiple classes can get high score as it's not a one-vs-all.
2. Your dataset only has one label for each datapoint when in reality multiple are possible. So you should augment your dataset. Below is one method I can think of

First create a similarity measure for the input items. Idea is you should be able to score 2 items based on how similar they are. It could be based on jaccard similarity of words, doc2vec embedding or some other similarity measure that works for the data.
Then for each input item, you should get a list of new additional labels based on labels of top-n most similar item to itself.

This way you will get much better list of labels and multi label problem should work well